# how to transfer files from mac desktop to an external harddrive

Tags: hard-drive, external-disk

I have files on the mac desktop that I want to transfer to a brand new external harddrive. I do not understand why it is not a straight forward matter. I am trying to drag the files I want to transfer from desktop to the new external harddrive folder but I cannot transfer the files.

Why is this not a straightforward affair?

Comment: It's very hard to tell what's wrong because you're not proving any info other than its not working. See [ask] for tips on asking questions including OS version, steps performed, error messages, console output, etc.

Comment: There are no error messages. I simply cannot drag and drop files from source to the destination (external hard drive). The 'block' sign appears and when I drop them to the destination folder, the file 'returns' to the original source folder and does not copy.

Comment: If this is a brand new external hard drive, it may not be properly formatted to be used with macOS. You should be able to use Disk Utility to check the current format of the external hard drive, and to reformat it to a format that macOS can write to.

Comment: Double check you have correct permissions on the files and drive (Cmd + I) and use disk utility to double check the formatting of the drive (if it’s empty, reformatting may help) as well as check to make sure it’s not a read only drive.

Comment: I bet you it’s because the drive is formatted in NTFS by default and that MacOS/OSX can not write to that HDD foray out of the box.

Comment: Yes, it is the NTFS problem. Thank you all. My first time using a brand new harddrive on a brand new mac.